# Value to type runtime mapping

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Consider this code

```
enum Types
{
    t1,
    t2
};

struct Base 
{
    Types typeTag;
    Base(Types t) : typeTag(t){}
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base 
{
    using Base::Base;
    T makeT() { return T(); }
};

int main() 
{
    Base *b = new Derived<std::string>(t1);
    auto d = getDerivedByTag(b); // How ??
    d->makeT();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to restore Derived type parameter by Base::typeTag value in runtime? Obviously, some external preliminarily prepared mapping is needed, but I can't figure out the exact way.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is basically a [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) that is not (yet) supported in C++. There are ways to simulate it or work around it but they are often verbose and not elegant. I would suggest rethinking your design, particularly your use of `auto`. It is not supposed to substitute for "any type" as you seem to imply by your code. It is meant as simplification of code when actual type is long or obfuscated (often happens with templates), nested etc. Not when you do not know the type! Because then you cannot really use it, can you.

So what you will have to do in one way or another is check the `typeTag` directly and continue based on that information. Alternatively you would need to use polymorphism using the `Base` directly (calling virtual methods propagated to `Derived`). For type unions you could use `boost::variant` (if you do not care what type `Derived` template argument is) or some other framework/library alternative like `QVariant` in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.

```
#include "iostream"
enum Types
{
    t1,
    t2
};

template<typename T>
struct Base 
{
    typedef T DerivedType;
    Types typeTag;
    Base(Types t) : typeTag(t){}
    DerivedType* operator()() {
      return static_cast<DerivedType*>(this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<Derived<T>>
{
    Derived(Types t): Base<Derived<T>>(t) {}
    T makeT() { return T(); }
};

int main() 
{
    Base<Derived<std::string>> *b = new Derived<std::string>(t1);
    auto d = (*b)();
    d->makeT();
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/uBsFD8

My implementation has nothing to do with typeTag.

Do you mean `getDerivedByTag(b->typeTag)` rather than `getDerivedByTag(b)`?